# Stackdriver Alerts Policy has stopped working

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I created a lot of logging metrics and alert policies in line with CIS Benchmark requirements, and in testing this, it worked fine. But only for while. Now, when I go to edit the logging metric I can see that changes I perform are displayed in the results using the filter I have, but when I go to Stackdriver and look at the alert policy, it hasn't picked up anything. I haven't changed anything to my knowledge.

Here are the commands I've used to create all this:

```
gcloud beta logging metrics create vpc_firewall_changes \
      --description="Actions related to VPC firewall changes (CIS 2.7)" \
      --log-filter="resource.type=\"gce_firewall_rule\" AND \
                    jsonPayload.event_subtype=\"compute.firewalls.patch\" OR \
                    jsonPayload.event_subtype=\"compute.firewalls.insert\""

gcloud alpha monitoring channels create \
      --type=email \
      --display-name="VPC Firewall Changes" \
      --description="E-mail channel for alerting VPC firewall changes" \
      --channel-labels=email_address=[my email]

gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
      --notification-channels=[channel uri] \
      --condition-filter="resource.type=\"global\" AND metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/vpc_firewall_changes\"" \
      --aggregation="{
        \"alignmentPeriod\": \"60s\", \
        \"crossSeriesReducer\": \"REDUCE_COUNT\", \
        \"perSeriesAligner\": \"ALIGN_RATE\" \
        }" \
      --condition-display-name="logging/user/vpc_firewall_changes [COUNT]" \
      --duration=60s \
      --if="> 0.001" \
      --trigger-count=1 \
      --combiner=OR \
      --display-name="VPC Firewall Changes Alerts" \
      --documentation="You are receiving this alert because changes have been made relating to the VPC firewall rules."
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: This is purely a guess on my part ... however it looks like these APIs for working with API creation of policies and alerts is flagged as Alpha functions.  This sends warning bells to me that something may be broken, in flux or otherwise suspicious.  My thinking is that if you signed up for Alpha, the chances are good that you got a contact at Google to raise issues.  Might you be able to file a ticket on what you found?  Google might be really keen to hear that alpha code you are testing for them is giving puzzles?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The thing is that a policy created this way worked, it was sending messages, and with no changes, the messages stopped. So I don't think it has anything to do with the API. I just found the API by searching for it, I never signed up for any alpha, so I don't have a contact to write to. I'll try creating an alert manually through the console and see if it makes a difference. On holiday at the moment, so won't be right now.

Comment: It seems to work again now, without any changes. I guess taking a holiday helps :)